# Responsive CSS sprites which are used as hyperlinks don't resize

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, responsive-design, sprite

Okay I searched the internet and stackoverflow, but I am still dazzled.

I am currently building a personal starting page (when you open your webbrowser it will start on this page) for me and my family. Most stuff is up and working and I started to use CSS sprites, because I do want to keep the load down. Now at first I started to use several different sprites and hide them depending on which resolution is being used with the @media rule.

Then I started to think; I would still be wasting bandwith and increasing download times, because it would still load 3 different sprites (for 3 different resolutions). So I searched Google and found that it's possible to create something called 'Responsive CSS sprites' or similar. However, this is were I experience problems.

I used the following generator: http://responsive-css.spritegen.com

Adjustsed the output a bit and put it on my website. Though the images (= sprites) do show up, are clickable and also hover / active both work, it just doesn't resize them at all for some reason. And I really don't know what I am doing wrong here. Maybe someone can explain me what I should do or what I am doing wrong.

Below is a partial piece of the coding (html and css) I am currently using.

CSS part:

```
.router, .diskstation, .sabnzbd, .couchpotato, .sickbeard, .vanderlingen, .neverlands, .linkplanet, .dszl{ max-width: 100%; background-size: 500%; background-image: url('../../../img/knoppen/navigatie-knoppen.hr.png'); }

.router { background-position: 0 88.461538%; background-size: 138.709677%; }
.router:hover { background-position: 0 84.615385%; background-size: 138.709677%; }
.router:active { background-position: 0 80.769231%; background-size: 138.709677%; }
.diskstation { background-position: 0 30.769231%; background-size: 108.860759%; }
.diskstation:hover { background-position: 0 26.923077%; background-size: 108.860759%; }
.diskstation:active { background-position: 0 23.076923%; background-size: 108.860759%; }
.sabnzbd { background-position: 0 76.923077%; background-size: 130.30303%; }
.sabnzbd:hover { background-position: 0 73.076923%; background-size: 130.30303%; }
.sabnzbd:active { background-position: 0 69.230769%; background-size: 130.30303%; }
.couchpotato { background-position: 0 19.230769%; background-size: 101.176471%; }
.couchpotato:hover { background-position: 0 15.384615%; background-size: 101.176471%; }
.couchpotato:active { background-position: 0 11.538462%; background-size: 101.176471%; }
.sickbeard { background-position: 0 65.384615%; background-size: 117.808219%; }
.sickbeard:hover { background-position: 0 61.538462%; background-size: 117.808219%; }
.sickbeard:active { background-position: 0 57.692308%; background-size: 117.808219%; }
```

This is only a small part of the CSS sprites I use, but you get the idea.
Also, this is the code I got from the generator, well at least the most of it. :)

And here is the HTML part:

```
<a href="router.php"><img class="router" alt="" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAHwAAABDAQMAAABk/POFAAAAA1BMVEX///+nxBvIAAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAABJJREFUeNpjYBgFo2AUjAK6AQAEcwABmWJweQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="></a>
<a href="diskstation.php"><img class="diskstation" alt="" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAJ4AAABDAQMAAABX6y7JAAAAA1BMVEX///+nxBvIAAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAABRJREFUeNpjYBgFo2AUjIJRMAAAAAV/AAHDdSA9AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC"></a>
<a href="sabnzbd.php"><img class="sabnzbd" alt="" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAIQAAABDAQMAAABnZz/oAAAAA1BMVEX///+nxBvIAAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAABJJREFUeNpjYBgFo2AUjIKhBAAEtgABaCn4jwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="></a>
<a href="couchpotato.php"><img class="couchpotato" alt="" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAKoAAABDAQMAAAA28wyLAAAAA1BMVEX///+nxBvIAAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAABRJREFUeNpjYBgFo2AUjIJRMGIBAAYFAAFf0+w8AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC"></a>
<a href="sickbeard.php"><img class="sickbeard" alt="" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAJIAAABDAQMAAABN185HAAAAA1BMVEX///+nxBvIAAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAABRJREFUeNpjYBgFo2AUjIJRQCoAAAU8AAF2NOTmAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC"></a>
```

As mentioned above; the images (= sprites) show up correctly and are clickable; even :hover and :active both work, however it just doesn't scale them, when I resize the window...?

To clarify what I am trying to achieve here; I just want the images to resize on lower resolutions. For example if my dad uses the website, it should make the images smaller, if I use the website at home it shouldn't resize (and keep their original values).

I don't know if I explained correctly; English isn't my native language, but I think I am pretty clear (if I say so myself).

Thank you all in advance for your help and input...!

**//update #1**

In response to user3125923

What you said actually made sense, so I put each sprite in a class called sprite_class. Next I added the @media stuff to my CSS which looks like:

```
@media (min-width:2048px){
.sprite_class{width:90%;
}
}

@media (min-width:1301px) and (max-width:1983px){
.sprite_class{width:60%;
}
}

@media (max-width:1300px){
.sprite_class{width:30%;
}
}
```

However, unfortunately, they still don't resize. Probably I am doing something wrong, but no clue to what... :(

**//update #2**

Well made a bit of progress here. Instead of resizing them to a smaller image, it enlarges the sprites?! When I set width:100% it will enlarge the image a lot of times. Should I set each div to a maximum amount in pixel? For example: max-width:128px

Will try that in the meantime, see if that works, though I think there should be an easier way.

**//update #3**

Pfft... I give up. I have no clue what I am doing here. I am currently only making things worse and worse. Now I managed to scale to lower resolutions, however now they have empty space between the images (think it's caused by a width setting somewhere), so even if it scales down (depending on resolution) it still takes up the original space. Very, very tiresome. Especially considering I have been busy with this crap for over a day now. Also the hover / active images don't properly align anymore with the original image. Getting sick and tired of this.......!

I think I will just create 3 seperate sprite sets and hide the ones which aren't used. Sure, it will increase the load, but at least I know that works. Fun for people who understand all of this, but...

**//update #4**

As mentioned in update #4 I got tired of all the time I spend on this. Nothing worked (probably my fault, but still very, very annoying). So I created 3 seperate sprite images and it now only loads the correct one depending on the resolution being used. Problem solved. Took me less than 3 minutes. Which is better than the headache the "do-it-the-correct-way" gave me...

I will check back in a day or so, to see if someone else has posted a working solution, other than the one I described in previous paragraph...

Comment: As i can see you are increasing only the background size. Have you tried to increase the container width also?

Answer (score 0):

You could add the sprites as you did before using media queries, there would be no need to load 3 images, just scale down the one sprite depending on the size of the screen. Something like:

```
@media screen (min-width 767px) {
 .sprite_class {
  width: 100%;
}
}

@media screen (max-width 768px) {
 .sprite_class {
  width: 70%;
}
}
```

And so on.

Comment: Bleh, it was pointless. I only managed to ruin everything. I give up. Getting a headache of this crap.

Comment: Could try make sure the surrounding containers/divs of the sprites are also defined by % widths, this should ensure that the sprites scale properly.